# Azure Cloud Configure Tab is disable in Cloud Services

Tags: azure

I am trying to enable the verbose monitoring for the cloud services. After reading documentation and lots of blog posts this can be done in the configure tab of the cloud service.

But the configure tab is disabled for that cloud service. Can to enable the verbose monitoring for that cloud service. I am struck at this.

I am running out of ideas. will appreciate can some one shed some light and help me on this.

Comment: Are you using the build in diagnostics and trace listeneres? You could try to change it to verbose in visual studio. Server Explorer -> Windows Azure -> Cloud Services -> your service -> change diagnostics.

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio,

1. Locate your cloud project.
2. Locate the role (under 'Roles' folder) and open it (double click it).
3. Under the 'Diagnostics' section, make sure 'Enable Diagnostics' is clicked.
4. In addition, you may prefer to not use the default option, and to instead specify what storage account is used to store diagnostics info. If so, under "Specify the storage account credentials for the Diagnostics results:", click the [...] box, and click 'Your subscription' radio button, and then you'll have a drop down of storage accounts to select from.

Republish your cloud service.

I did this and it fixed the problem where the monitoring Minimal / Verbose option was grayed out and not available, as well as the Diagnostics Connection Strings under that having been empty.

Comment: Somewhat related: is there a way to make it Verbose by default? I need verbose logging for auditing purposes in my worker role.